# All my content won't appear in globalstyle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I'm trying to create a GlobalStyle with styled components but when I added it into my `App.js` all my content disappear

Here is my `App.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import GlobalStyle from "./Styles/GlobalStyle";
import SideNav from "./Components/SideNav";

function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalStyle>
      <SideNav />
    </GlobalStyle>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My `SideNav.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Link } from "@reach/router";

const Sidenav = styled.div`
  width: 200px;
`;

const ListItems = styled.ul`
  font-size: 10px;
`;

const Item = styled(Link)`
  list-style-type: none;
  display: block;
`;

const SideNav = (props) => {
  return (
    <Sidenav>
      <ListItems>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </ListItems>
    </Sidenav>
  );
};

export default SideNav;
```

and here is my `GlobalStyle.js`:

```
import {
    createGlobalStyle
} from 'styled-components';
import theme from './theme';
import FontFaces from './fonts'
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle `
  ${FontFaces};
  html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
  }
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    line-height: 1.3;
  }
`
export default GlobalStyle;
```

When I added

```
<GlobalStyle>
  <SideNav />
</GlobalStyle>
```

It hided my SideNav but when I take it out my SideNav will appear again. What's wrong with my GlobalStyle? Someone explain for me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You should render it like this.

```
import React from "react";
import GlobalStyle from "./Styles/GlobalStyle";
import SideNav from "./Components/SideNav";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <SideNav />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```